# Cannot get all the @override functions such as onStart, onResume in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio newest version. When I created my first `Activity` I cannot see all the functions in `MainActivity.java` Usually you get `onStart`, `onResume` etc.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm87y.png)

Comment: So just type them in. If you start typing the method name, I'd imagine your IDE will auto-complete them for you.

Comment: Usually you only get onCreate() method when activity is created. You have to override them manually

Comment: Ok  so you dont get all the functions. you have to manually enter them? i watched one of the video and dude had all the functions created like onpause, onstop etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ctrl+O to select functions to be Override